# Removing date and keeping time only from timestamp in a uneven pandas column

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime, time

I have the following dataframe structure:

[image: Data Info]

I would like to convert columns "Entr." and "Fim" to time (HH:MM), in the format: HH:MM:SS. I'm getting stuck converting 'cause the column is uneven: Sometimes appears a "-", sometimes it's on datetime format "DD-MM-YYYY HH:MM:SS" and sometimes on time "HH:MM:SS".

Columns:

[image: Columns]

---

Columns sample:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ujvPED0S1vPZ9bmCSob3vR68XwUXC2gk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I'm a bit unclear. Do you want to drop the rows that have the date or do you want to strip off the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading the Excel file leaves you with mixed datatype columns; some elements are `datetime.datetime` objects (e.g. `datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 10)` at df['Fim'].iloc[2]), some `datetime.time` (e.g. `datetime.time(13, 15)` at df['Fim'].iloc[0]). AFAIK that's related to how the libraries xlrd / openpyxl read the file - not much `pandas` can do about it. Related: [Pandas read excel returning type object when time is 00:00](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66479033/10197418).

**TLDR:**

cast everything to string and remove the dates. That leaves you with time in HH:MM:SS format.

```
df = pd.read_excel(filename)

df['Entr.'] = df['Entr.'].astype(str).str.split(' ').str[-1]
df['Fim'] = df['Fim'].astype(str).str.split(' ').str[-1]
```

```
df.head()

      Entr.       Fim
0  05:25:00  13:15:00
1  13:15:00  16:00:00
2  16:00:00  00:10:00
3  03:30:00  11:18:00
4  11:18:00  18:00:00
```

Answer (score -1):

Import dateutil
dateutil.parser.parse("1900-01-01 02:32:00")

Comment: Another way will be using time=date.split("\n")[1]